# Use Remote MySQL Database On Heroku With Django Server

Tags: mysql, django, heroku, remote-access

Can I use mysql database from my personal web server instead of heroku's database?

in django settings I have this for databses:

```
DATABASES={

'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    'HOST': 'x.x.x.x',   
    'PORT': '3306',
}
}
```

what should be my settings.py databases part?
or do I need anything more to do?

Comment: Why, what's the problem with Heroku's database?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Apart from the latency as iklnac points out, you are losing most of the benefits of getting Heroku to manage your infrastructure in the first place. After all, if you manage your own MySQL, why not also manage your own hosting and not bother with Heroku at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use your personal MySQL server but there are **big drawbacks** in following as servers are not on the same network so you are introducing **latency** in each query.

To do following things that are necessary is that Heroku node can access your MySQL server and that your MySQL user can connect to your database from the node.